# Does publishing my story on sites like Royal Road or ScribbleHub reduce (or increase) the story's market value? Why?

Tags: publishing, web-novel

I read dozens of stories serialized on the web, for free, on sites like Royal Road and ScribbleHub.

And several of them sign contracts with publishers, get *"sold"* to the 'zon, audiobook, print-on-demand, the whole nine yards.

But people have already read the story online. While some programs require the original to be taken down, the story is no longer unpublished.

Does publishing these stories for free on these sites have any effect on the story's value? If so, then why?

Comment: I am not sure that what you see actually means that stories from those sites gain contracts and get sold. Print on demand is most certainly self-publishing, and Amazon and audiobooks can mean self-publishing, too. You'd have to look at the examples you saw more closely and identify who the publisher actually is. I strongly assume that the authors that put their stories on Royal Road and ScribbleHub later (or at the same time) decided to self-publish it through those other channels, too. As EDL pointed out, most publishers will not buy something that was previously published anywhere else.

Comment: @Ben you are mistaken. There are dozens of popular stories on the sites that are going to the KU via a publisher. Just check the front page and see how many stories there are stubbing because of the KU exclusivity. While there are some that self-publish, many more are signing with these publishers.

Comment: KU is self-publishing.

Comment: Notable stories bought by publishers after they’d been released on the internet are “The Martian”  by Andy Weir and The Murderbot Diaries, as series by Martha Wells.

Comment: And, more famously, *50 Shades of Grey*.

Comment: @Ben KU can be self-published but several sign with publishers. Just check how many stories are stubbed on RR and what label they go with on the KU.

Answer (score 0):

In general, publishers buy the first rights to publish a story, in a specific language or market – English rights in North America for instance.

If the story is accessible on the internet with unrestricted access then that expended the first rights. After that it is a reprint. Reprint rights are considered less valuable. It's more difficult for the publisher to assess the potential profits.

But the value of other languages markets are not be diminished — assuming you didn't write your story in English and Hindi simultaneously when you published it to the web. First rights to publish your story in Hindi or Greek still exist. This also applies to audiobooks, again assuming you hadn't read your book into an MP3 and put it on the internet for everyone's listening enjoyment.

The important part is the free unrestricted access. That is what consumes the first rights. If the story was behind a pay wall or you shared it on a site like critters.org (since the readership is restricted and known, and countable) you aren’t risking your first rights when sharing the story with critique communities or beta readers.